# How can I access to objects, properties and variables of a jQuery plugin instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I just created and developed a jQuery plugin and it is working fine. But when I call more than one instance of it, some functions will affect on another instance. For example, I have list of items and a "Delete" button before each item. When you click on each "Delete" item, following function will fire:

```
$('.del-item').each(function(){
        $(this).on('click',function(){
            var $e = $(this).parent();
            var val = $e.data('val');
            $sourceBox.find('.source-item[data-val='+val+']').removeClass('selected-item added').find('span').remove();
            $el.find('option[value='+val+']').removeAttr('selected').trigger('change');
            $el.trigger('change');
            $e.slideUp(200,function(){
                $e.remove();                
            });
        });
    });
```

But it removes items from another list or affect on another instance of plugin. Please advice how can I access to only related items?

Comment: What is `$el`? (As opposed to `$e`?)

Comment: To help you debug your plugin code, we have to see your plugin code. Or ideally, an [MCVE version of it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have multiple instances of jQuery plugin on single page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615894/how-to-have-multiple-instances-of-jquery-plugin-on-single-page)